# Remove every row where C cell doesn't contain 7 or 8 numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking around everywhere. But I don't know what words to google.

I want to remove every row where the cell in the C column doesn't contain 7 or 8 numbers. The problem is that I don't know how to code this.

What is the symbol in VBA code for 1 letter, 1 number, 1 or more letters, 1 or more numbers, space etc? I have been googling for hours but I guess I just don't know the right search words. Where or how can I find this? It's pretty dumb I know.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

@eirikdaude Thank you for your answer.

Somehow it doesn't work. This is what I have:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If (IsNumeric(Cells(i, 3).Value) And Len(Cells(i, 3).Value) >= 7 And Len(Cells(i, 3).Value) <= 8) Then

    ' do nothing

    Else
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next i
```

I've been trying everything, but I don't understand why this code above doesn't work.

Does it matter that all my cells are formatted "standard" in excel? Because all data is imported from a txt file.

Comment: Search this site for `[vba]regex`.

Comment: Okay thanks!! Regular expressions. Those two simple words is all I needed, perfect! Thanks again

Comment: Could you post what a sample column in your worksheet may look like? Also, when looping through rows in order to delete them, it is often smart to  start from the last row and move upwards, otherwise it is easy to skip e.g. what was previously row 3 when you delete row 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two probably reason for which you code is no deleting the expected rows:

1. Expected lines to be deleted may be skipped by the code as it's deleting rows from top to bottom. When deleting several rows the correct method is to do it upwards (i.e. from bottom to top)
2. As your data is imported from a text file it's possible that values in column `C` have some extra blank spaces at the end. The use of TRIM takes care of this situation.

The code below includes both corrections:

```
Sub Rng_Delete_Rows()
Dim LRowLst As Long, LRow As Long
Dim vCllVal As Variant

    'Change SheetName as required
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'Use this if procedure resides in Data workbook
    'With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'Use this if procedure does not reside in Data workbook
        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
        LRowLst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        For LRow = LRowLst To 2 Step -1
            Rem Get Cell Value At Once
            vCllVal = Trim(.Cells(LRow, 3).Value2)
            If Not ((IsNumeric(vCllVal) _
                And Len(vCllVal) >= 7 And Len(vCllVal) <= 8)) Then
                Rem Delete Row
                .Rows(LRow).EntireRow.Delete
    End If: Next: End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you insist on using a regex for this, I'd simply check for the length of the value in the cell and if it [`IsNumeric`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264560.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In your case, something like this:

```
For Each c In rangeToCheck
  If IsNumeric(c) And Len(c) >= 7 And Len(c) <=8) Then
    do your stuff
  End If
Next c
```

Comment: @Jeeped I suppose. Should probably be flagged as a duplicate and / or asking for external tools then?

Comment: That returns true for `IsNumeric`? I suppose it might, in which case a  different approach is in order ^_^ @pnuts